# Is it possible to index an exclamation point given in a macro argument?

Tags: indexing, makeindex

I have nearly the same problem as [this guy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324842/is-it-possible-to-index-an-exclamation-point) but the solution doesn't work for me, I think because the string I am indexing is in a macro argument.

From the other question:

> The characters `!`, `@`, and `|` need to be escaped in an indexing context. For makeindex to understand you mean to mention them rather than use them, you must 'quote' them with a `"`. The following should do the trick:
>
> `\index{"!} % or, in this case: \fun{"!}`

Applying this to my code I get

```
\newcommand{\coper}[1]%
{%
    \texttt{#1}%
    \ifthenelse%
        {\equal{#1}{!} \OR \equal{#1}{@}}%
        {%
            \index{"#1@\texttt{"#1} (C operator)}%
            \index{operators!\texttt{"#1} (C)}%
        }%
        {%
            \index{#1@\texttt{#1} (C operator)}%
            \index{operators!\texttt{#1} (C)}%
        }%
}
```

Invoking `\coper{!}` adds an entry to the index, but the exclamation point does not appear in the index (it's just blank, but the surrounding text is there).

How do I add the exclamation point to the index when it is given through a macro argument?

Comment: as always it would be better to put a complete documument showing the probkem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unrelated to `"` just as the error message indicates you have more `{` than `}`

i assume

```
 \index{"#1@\texttt{"#1} (C operator)%
```

was intended to be

```
 \index{"#1@\texttt{"#1} (C operator)}%
```

and

```
           \index{#1@\texttt{#1} (C operator)%
```

intended to be

```
           \index{#1@\texttt{#1} (C operator)}%
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx,ifthen}
\makeindex
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\coper}[1]%
{%
    \texttt{#1}%
    \ifthenelse%
        {\equal{#1}{!} \OR \equal{#1}{@}}%
        {%
            \index{"#1@\texttt{"#1} (C operator)}%
            \index{operators!\texttt{"#1} (C)}%
        }%
        {%
            \index{#1@\texttt{#1} (C operator)}%
            \index{operators!\texttt{#1} (C)}%
        }%
}

aaa\coper{!}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, that fixes the compile error, although I still don't have the desired result. I updated my question.

Comment: @spraff works for me, I added the output

Comment: I did a clean build and that fixed it. I've been getting a lot of n00b help from you, David, thanks a lot, much appreciated :-)